# ProLiant DL380 G8 restart after shutdown

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp, shutdown, reboot, hp-server-automation

I've just bought a HP DL360 gen8 server, but the issue is when i shutdown the server it do all its prosess but the led still glows and after 15-20 sec the server automatically starts again, can you guide me for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the power management/state settings in the RBSU/BIOS -

From the System Utilities screen, select System Configuration > BIOS/Platform Configuration (RBSU) > Server Availability > Automatic Power-On and press Enter.

Select a setting and press Enter.
Always Power On—The system automatically returns to a power on state.
Always Power Off—The system automatically returns to a power off state.
Restore Last Power State—The system automatically returns to its previous power off state.
Press F10

The power state might be set to automatic power on.

You could also check this in the iLO4 web interface, under Power Management>Server Power>Auto Power On

[iLO4 Web Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPfbv.png)